# React native different behaviour between debug mode and normal mode react-native": "0.60.4

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

React native different behavior between debug mode and normal mode
redux updation working properly in debug mode but not in normal mode, I am using `"react-native": "0.60.4".` 
and I tried JSC build scripts for Android (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsc-android). but still exists the problem, is there any solution?

Comment: You need to explain what the problem is. The only thing you said is that you have a problem. What works differently between debug and normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> while you running the app in emulator , emulator use the javascript engine of chrome, while you. running the app in your device its user javascript engine of your device, there is a chance decrease performance in device

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem related to using date in your app? Because in debug mode , react native uses a diff engine to render and in normal mode, it uses a diff engine.

Comment: I am not using any dates